# Initiate DataSource after Singleton Bean Wildfly

Tags: java, datasource, wildfly, startup

We use custom SingletonBean which works like secure key-value storage of different data. DB credentials also stored there, so for working on Wildfly we wrote JAAS LoginModule implementation, which then configured inside Wildfly Security Domain, and finally DataSource use this security-domain for credentials extraction.

When wildfly is starting it logs that DataSource failed to get connection. It happens because SingletonBean is not ready yet and JAAS Login module failed to extract credentials from them. Then we deploy some jar which uses hibernate. And it works pretty well because Wildfly try to initiate DataSource again and this attempt finishes with success.

Second scenario is when we restart wildfly. DS also complains to fail with initiating connection to DB. But this time deployed jar starting concurrently and unable to get proper PersistentContext.

So my idea was to make described processes to start consecutively. Is there any method to do that?

Here singleton bean definition

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class DirectoryServiceSingletonBean {
     ...
     @PostConstruct
     void startup() {
         // Post this bean to JNDI
     }
}
```

JAAS LoginModule

```
public class MyLoginModule extends AbstractPasswordCredentialLoginModule
{
     @Override
     public void initialize(
             Subject subject,
             CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
             Map<String, ?> sharedState,
             Map<String, ?> options) {

         addValidOptions(ALL_VALID_OPTIONS);
         super.initialize(subject, callbackHandler, sharedState, options);
         username = (String) options.get(USERNAME);
         // Extraction of DirectoryServiceSingletonBean bean from JNDI
         password = extractFrom(DirectoryServiceSingletonBean) 
    }
    ....
}
```

I tried to Use @DependsOn("DirectoryServiceSingletonBean") annotation on LoginModule and on @Stateless/@Statefull beans from deployment (They has @PersistentContext) but it doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried to add the datasource with Wildfly JNDI configuration.hope this [post](https://wiki.snowflakesoftware.com/display/GPWFSDOC/JNDI+Data+Source+Configuration+with+Wildfly+8) may be helpful.

Comment: Yes DS is available through JNDI, even more i am to retrieve it from JNDI and bypassing Hibernate and manually get connection. Driver (Oracle) and DS were added to wildfly via JBoss-cli commands.

Comment: If the JAAS LoginModule secures the application containing the `DirectoryServiceSingletonBean` then you have a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Deployment with DirectoryServiceSingletonBean is absolutely separate. And its only purpose is to provide this bean. JAAS Login module used only for DataSource credentials extraction. No Chicken-egg problem. Problem is that hen try to tear down the egg before rooster do his job with hen.

Comment: So you're looking up the `DirectoryServiceSingletonBean` in JNDI?

Comment: BTW, you know that WildFly has it's own secure vault that you can use for credential storage don't you?

Comment: Yes i am looking up DirectoryServiceSingletonBean in JNDI. Generally it ok, problem is during Wildfly startup, when Wildfly tries to initiate @PersistenceContext for deployment beans, but fails because DataSource is not ready yet due to database credentials absence because JAAS Login Module fails to retrieve DirectoryServiceSingletonBean from JNDI because it hasn't ready yet (Its @Pre/Post construct methods don't finished yet).

Yes i read about Wildfly credentials storages but i forced to use DirectoryServiceSingletonBean due to some policies in our environment.